# How do i extrapolate function name in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this

```
Subject.books()
```

that works great, but now at one place in code i just have the string 'books()', this string could basically be anything you want, i just want it to eval and evaluate the function and give me the same result as above. How do i do it?

Comment: Do you have string 'books()' i.e. with brackets or just 'books'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Square bracket notation:

```
Subject['someString']();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects